# SWF flash animation doesn't work correctly

Tags: html, object, flash

At my [page](http://www.vazaky.com/) is a flash animation - under the logo. The problem is, that the animation doesn't works correctly - is slow, the images in the animation are blurred etc. If I play the animation in **Elmedia Player**, there it works nice, but on the website not.

I included the animation into the page this way:

```
<div>
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/images/intro.swf" width="986" height="110">
    <param name="movie" value="/images/intro.swf" />
  </object>
</div>
```

Where could be the issue / how could I this issue fix?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try your page in two different browsers I get an error with the GMap2. Maybe this is stopping your flash being embedded?

```
 var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
```

Comment: I tried to remove all JS on the page, but unfortunately the result is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your embed code is apparently not working. For compatibility with all major browsers and generally hassle-free embedding of Flash movies in HTML pages, I really recommend [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

It has a [handy generator GUI](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/list) that sets up all the code for you and all you have to do is copy+paste.

Comment: It's not the embedding code, it's the swf file itself which isn't working. What's in the code? do you use any events to detect if the file/images finished loading?

Comment: I can't see the Flash at all on Firefox, it's just a blank space.. That's why my assessment was that the embed code was a problem.

Comment: The flash file is there: http://www.vazaky.com/images/intro.swf it doesn't play in the browser, however it plays in the standalone player. For test purposes I have created a simple HTML and embedded the file with SWFObject - it didn't work.

Comment: Dude, you've got a problem with your webserver. I get a "206 Partial Content" response, instead of the usual "200 OK".